# Why class can be treated as std::function<float()> but shared_ptr cannot be treated as std::shared_ptr<std::function<float()>>

Tags: c++, polymorphism

There was some code that was able to treat a class that implements `operator()` as an `std::function`. I then tried to do the same but using `shared_ptr`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class WhiteNoise  {
public:
    WhiteNoise()  {}
    float operator() () {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    //fails
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<float()>> = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::function<float()>>(std::make_shared<WhiteNoise>());
    //fails
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<float()>> = std::make_shared<WhiteNoise>();
    //works
    std::function<float()> f = WhiteNoise();
}
```

Why I can treat `WhiteNoise` as `std::function<float()>` but not `shared_ptr<WhiteNoise>` as `shared_ptr<std::function<float()>>`

Comment: Do you understand the difference between converting from type A to B, and having type A and B inherit from one another?

Comment: @alterigel rigth. Can I inherit from `std::function<float()>` then?

Comment: you _could_, but it would be very strange to do so. Have you considered creating your own base class, e.g. `class INoise { public: virtual ~INoise() noexcept = default; float operator()() = 0; };`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs What are you really trying to accomplish with such odd conversions?

Comment: What is the use of having a `shared_ptr<std::function<...>>`? Why not just a `std::function<...>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why I can treat `WhiteNoise` as `std::function<float()>` but not `shared_ptr<WhiteNoise>` as `shared_ptr<std::function<float()>>`

For a similar reason why an `int` can be assigned to a `double`, but an `int*` can't be assigned to a `double*`.  Because there is a defined conversion from `int` to `double`, but there is no defined conversion between unrelated pointer types.

Likewise, there is a defined conversion for a callable function object to a `std::function`.  The `std::function` will make a copy of the object, and call its implemented `operator()` when needed.

But there is no defined conversion from a `std::shared_ptr<T>` (ie `T*`) to a `std::shared_ptr<std::function>` (ie `std::function*`) when `T` is not itself a `std::function`.

If you have a `std::shared_ptr<WhiteNoise>` and you want to make a `std::shared_ptr<std::function<float()>>` out of it (why?), you could do something like this instead:

```cpp
auto wn = std::make_shared<WhiteNoise>();
auto func = std::make_shared<std::function<float()>>(*wn);
float f = (*func)();
```

Comment: Can I make `WhiteNoise` inherit from `std::function` then?

Comment: No, nor should you want/need to. But you could use ie `auto wn = std::make_shared<WhiteNoise>(); auto f = std::make_shared<std::function<float()>>(*wn);` instead.